# How can I install my C++ library on my client's machine?

Tags: installation

I have written a C++ library which will be used for POS applications,
Library are to be distributed as binaries(DLL only for windows) to customers

I have understood that library can be used in 3 ways on client machine

1. By placing binaries in the directory/folder of application executable
2. By copying binaries to system32 directory
3. By adding path of the binaries on client machine to PATH environment variable

Kindly educate me if there is a better way of installing library on the client machine,
Which is the best way to install the distributed binaries on the client machine?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't write your titles entirely in capital letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend you, to put the library into the application folder: Putting it into system32 is an invitation to DLL hell: A newer version in the app directory would be overruled by an older version in system32.

There is quite an easy rule:

- if the library is intended for a special application, store it with the app
- if the library is intended for general consumption, store it in system32

Answer (score 0):

I always bind the dll's in my application. Its the safest approach i know.